# how to return a value from factored intervals of create_qgroups() in r

Tags: r, vector, numeric, quantile

I have a data frame. I create a quantile group based on its values.

```
 library(dvmisc)
 my_vec <- c(415.5326,   138.4831,   658.7316,   737.5037,   773.5543, 
 2062.0428,    79.7115,   473.2346) 
 my_q_grp <- create_qgroups(my_vec, groups = 4)
```

so out put is

```
(346,566]  [-Inf,346] (566,747]  (566,747]  (747, Inf] (747, Inf] [-Inf,346] (346,566] 
Levels: [-Inf,346] (346,566] (566,747] (747, Inf]
```

I want a vector whose values are max value in each interval
like (566,346,747,...,inf)   but my_vec is factor. I do not know how to do this.

Comment: include the function as well, so we can play around with the structure of the resulting factor; Are you using findInterval with this?

Comment: I am using create_qgroups() this gives me intervals based on quantile. as shown in the post above.

Comment: That's not a base R function. You've got to state where you got that from. I've looked it up and it comes from `{dvmisc}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to extract the right part of intervals:

```r
right_part <- .  %>% 
  #' remove this if you want to do it on each value of the factor
  # levels() %>% 
  str_match("[(\\[](.+)[,](.+)[)\\]]") %>% 
  `[`(,3) %>% 
  as.numeric()
right_part(my_q_grp)
```

Comment: thank you but this gives 346 566 747 Inf which is clearly different with (566,346,747,...,inf) that I want

Comment: Yes, I wrote comment out the `levels()` part if you want the right side of each value in the factor.